# Integração Moodle com sistema de terceiros

Tags: integração, moodle

Olá, Tenho hoje uma dúvida cruel.
Preciso fazer com que o portal moodle trabalhe com os usuários de um sistema externo.

Alguém já conseguiu fazer isso com poucas alterações no código fonte do moodle?

Comment: Pelo pouco que mexi com isso acho que é tenso modificar o moodle, talvez, você não pode fazer uma espécie de mascara e logar no moodle via requisição http com a classe guzzle ? Ai você só precisaria linkar os teus usuários com outros usuários cadastrados no moodle, mas como eu disse não vi quase nada de como o moodle funciona, é apenas uma sugestão.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. O problema é o moodle mesmo configurado para login em base externa traz o usuário para a base própria e quando o usuário modifica o perfil e senha fica complicadissímo trazer e atualizar o sistema educacional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a própria API do Moodle para realizar as integrações, dessa forma você não precisará modificar o core do Moodle.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

Aqui no GitHub tem alguns exemplos para a utilização:

https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients